# Cppcheck XML output to file

Tags: xml

I'm running CPPcheck from command line like this:

```
cppcheck --xml folderWithCPPfiles
```

The output of this is following:

```
113/118 files checked 95% done
Checking folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp ...
        <error id="returnDanglingLifetime" severity="error" msg="Returning pointer to local variable &apos;c&apos; that will be invalid when returning." verbose="Returning pointer to local variable &apos;c&apos; that will be invalid when returning." cwe="562" hash="8042533878513096525">
            <location file0="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" file="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" line="4" column="13"/>
            <location file0="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" file="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" line="3" column="11" info="Variable created here."/>
            <location file0="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" file="folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp" line="4" column="13" info="Address of variable taken here."/>
        </error>
114/118 files checked 96% done
Checking folderWithCPPfiles\19395.cpp ...
```

Now I'm trying to put the xml output into some specific folder, like output.xml:

```
cppcheck --xml folderWithCPPfiles > "C:\Users\me\Documents\allData\output.xml"
```

This command indeed creates new file `output.xml`, but it only puts there the non-xml output, so from the output shown above, only:

```
113/118 files checked 95% done
Checking folderWithCPPfiles\19389.cpp ...
114/118 files checked 96% done
Checking folderWithCPPfiles\19395.cpp ...
```

Hence the result xml file is incorrect. Do you have any idea how to put the xml content only in my output.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

cppcheck --xml folderWithCPPfiles 2> "C:\Users\me\Documents\allData\output.xml"